# Loading previous version workflows with new version assembly

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation

I am trying to figure out a way to upgrade assemblies used by our worklow runtime (*custom activities*) while still being able to load (*deserialize*) old instances.
My situation is like this:

1. have a workflow instance created and persisted with `CustomActivities` v.1.0.0.0
2. deploy a new version of the product witch has `CustomActivities` v.2.0.0.0
3. try to load previous workflows in the new runtime

The difference between v.1 and v.2 is that we have some extra classes in the assembly. The structure for the existing types has not changed so i would presume that binary deserialization would still work.
 We are redirecting all types from v.1 to v.2 using `AssemblyResolve` event

```cs
if (args.Name.Contains("CustomActivities"))
{
    Type someTypeFromCustomActivities = typeof(WorkflowType);
    return someTypeFromCustomActivities.Assembly;
}
```

Yet at some point during the deserialization process we are getting the following exception:

> SerializationException: The object with ID 153 implements the IObjectReference interface for which all dependencies cannot be resolved. The likely cause is two instances of IObjectReference that have a mutual dependency on each other.

What might cause this behavior and how can we work around it?
Also if anyone has a strategy for upgrading workflows that does not involve running side by side assemblies (*old and new versions in the same app domain*) they would be welcomed.

Comment: This blog says: 
> Check if you changed your workflow (created some new state for example), if so check if your persistance database have any persisted workflow in it. if it have your problem could be there because the workflow cannot be serialized again. 

> @AZ Could this be your case? http://brazeta.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/vs-2010-test-assert-inconclusive-exception/

Comment: The class/workflow structure has not changed a bit. Also i can not just delete the persisted data because that would mean i lose active production workflows

Answer (score 2):

The assembly resolve event does nothing for changing the serialized types assembly references. Have you tried an assembly binding redirect at the machine level from v1 to v2.

Update:  I did find this link that talks about using a binding redirect to forward old workflows to new versions using an appliesTo attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa349375.aspx

Comment: the assembly resolve handling has exactly the same effect as the config redirect. In theory the old data should match the new types as nothing has changed in their structure yet still the workflow runtime fails with the above exception. I'm trying to get some advice from people that have encountered this issue before and how they devised a solution if any.

Comment: - 1 for not an answer. this could have been a nice comment though

Comment: I was in the airport while I was writing this on my phone, so I apologize for the brevity and lack of clarity and having the answer in the wrong spot.

Comment: no need for appologies. tx for taking the time to look at the question. -1 retracted :)